# Android onPause() called after onStop()

Tags: java, android, lockscreen, onpause

I'm trying to display an `Activity` over lockscreen. The `Activity` is displayed for a few moments and then crashes. This happens only on a particular device (Sony Xperia Z2), the app is running completely fine on a variety of other devices.

According to log, `onPause()` is called after `onStop()`:

```
10-28 16:14:03.079: D/AlarmAlert(29630): onCreate CALLED
10-28 16:14:03.099: D/AlarmAlert(29630): onCreate DONE
10-28 16:14:03.099: D/AlarmAlert(29630): onResume
10-28 16:14:03.109: D/AlarmAlert(29630): onPause
10-28 16:14:03.119: D/QSEECOMAPI:(322): Loaded image: APP id = 4
10-28 16:14:03.139: W/SurfaceFlinger(320): couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
10-28 16:14:03.149: E/suntrolkac(396): props_GetStatusForAllKeys :: KEY_TYPE=106, KEY_STATUS=1
10-28 16:14:03.149: E/suntrolkac(396): props_GetStatusForAllKeys :: data=marlin,1, status=1
10-28 16:14:03.149: E/suntrolkac(396): props_GetStatusForAllKeys :: KEY_TYPE=109, KEY_STATUS=1
10-28 16:14:03.149: E/suntrolkac(396): props_GetStatusForAllKeys :: data=playready,1, status=1
10-28 16:14:03.149: E/suntrolkac(396): props_GetStatusForAllKeys :: KEY_TYPE=110, KEY_STATUS=1
10-28 16:14:03.149: E/suntrolkac(396): props_GetStatusForAllKeys :: data=dtla,1, status=1
10-28 16:14:03.149: E/suntrolkac(396): props_GetStatusForAllKeys :: KEY_TYPE=111, KEY_STATUS=1
10-28 16:14:03.149: E/suntrolkac(396): props_GetStatusForAllKeys :: data=marlin_import,1, status=1
10-28 16:14:03.149: E/suntrolkac(396): props_GetStatusForAllKeys :: KEY_TYPE=112, KEY_STATUS=1
10-28 16:14:03.149: E/suntrolkac(396): props_GetStatusForAllKeys :: data=ckb,1, status=1
10-28 16:14:03.149: E/suntrolkac(396): props_GetStatusForAllKeys :: KEY_TYPE=113, KEY_STATUS=1
10-28 16:14:03.149: E/suntrolkac(396): props_GetStatusForAllKeys :: data=widevine,1, status=1
10-28 16:14:03.149: E/suntrolkac(396): props_GetStatusForAllKeys :: KEY_TYPE=114, KEY_STATUS=1
10-28 16:14:03.149: E/suntrolkac(396): props_GetStatusForAllKeys :: data=dcp,1, status=1
10-28 16:14:03.149: I/ActivityManager(29630): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.mypackage.alarm time:34436028
10-28 16:14:03.149: I/ActivityManager(989): START u0 {flg=0x10040000 cmp=com.mypackage.alarm/.AlarmAlert} from pid 29630
10-28 16:14:03.179: E/AudioSink(308): received unknown event type: 1 inside CallbackWrapper !
10-28 16:14:03.199: E/AudioSink(308): received unknown event type: 1 inside CallbackWrapper !
10-28 16:14:03.239: D/AlarmAlert(29630): onStop
10-28 16:14:03.279: I/ActivityManager(29630): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@4487f768 time:34436159
10-28 16:14:03.359: D/dalvikvm(23275): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1210K, 9% free 53975K/59108K, paused 7ms+18ms, total 92ms
10-28 16:14:03.359: D/dalvikvm(23275): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 44ms
10-28 16:14:03.359: W/eqb(23275): Finalizing LiveList without having stopped producer: eom{type=SAPI_LL_TYPE_PREFETCH_DETAILED_ITEMS, priority=DEFAULT, isPaused=false, #elements=0}
10-28 16:14:03.359: W/eqb(23275): Finalizing LiveList without having stopped producer: eom{type=SAPI_LL_TYPE_PREFETCH_DETAILED_ITEMS, priority=DEFAULT, isPaused=false, #elements=0}
10-28 16:14:03.359: D/dalvikvm(23275): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 46ms
10-28 16:14:03.369: D/dalvikvm(23275): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 55ms
10-28 16:14:03.509: W/cumulus(23275): iup: Disposing queries [66d230c9722515cd, 315aba24fcc62b40, 58661e75e6173090, 158eab12335e048f, 21682fbd5a0aee5, 8faf972cbd2d5fa, 34797718aabd5c44, 1907fb5f55c1a2b9, 3b40d400e43e2c7]
10-28 16:14:03.509: W/cumulus(23275): hqt: Channel closed.
10-28 16:14:03.539: D/dalvikvm(989): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2434K, 14% free 86915K/100260K, paused 183ms, total 183ms
10-28 16:14:03.549: D/AlarmAlert(29630): onPause
10-28 16:14:03.549: D/QSEECOMAPI:(322): QSEECom_dealloc_memory 
10-28 16:14:03.549: D/QSEECOMAPI:(322): QSEECom_shutdown_app, app_id = 4
10-28 16:14:03.549: I/ActivityManager(989): Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{4508a378 u0 com.mypackage.alarm/.AlarmAlert t176 f} time:34436428
10-28 16:14:03.549: E/ActivityThread(29630): Performing pause of activity that is not resumed: {com.mypackage.alarm/com.mypackage.alarm.AlarmAlert}
10-28 16:14:03.549: E/ActivityThread(29630): java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing pause of activity that is not resumed: {com.mypackage.alarm/com.mypackage.alarm.AlarmAlert}
10-28 16:14:03.549: E/ActivityThread(29630):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3133)
10-28 16:14:03.549: E/ActivityThread(29630):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3121)
10-28 16:14:03.549: E/ActivityThread(29630):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3099)
10-28 16:14:03.549: E/ActivityThread(29630):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:144)
10-28 16:14:03.549: E/ActivityThread(29630):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1263)
10-28 16:14:03.549: E/ActivityThread(29630):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-28 16:14:03.549: E/ActivityThread(29630):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
10-28 16:14:03.549: E/ActivityThread(29630):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5151)
10-28 16:14:03.549: E/ActivityThread(29630):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-28 16:14:03.549: E/ActivityThread(29630):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-28 16:14:03.549: E/ActivityThread(29630):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-28 16:14:03.549: E/ActivityThread(29630):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)
10-28 16:14:03.549: E/ActivityThread(29630):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-28 16:14:03.559: I/ActivityManager(989): Activity reported stop, but no longer stopping: ActivityRecord{4508a378 u0 com.mypackage.alarm/.AlarmAlert t176 f}
10-28 16:14:03.559: W/ActivityManager(989): Activity ActivityRecord{4508a378 u0 com.mypackage.alarm/.AlarmAlert t176 f} being finished, but not in LRU list
10-28 16:14:03.569: I/PowerManagerService(989): Waking up from sleep...
10-28 16:14:03.579: D/SurfaceFlinger(320): Screen acquired, type=0 flinger=0xb87e5130
10-28 16:14:03.579: D/qdhwcomposer(320): hwc_blank: Unblanking display: 0
10-28 16:14:03.589: D/PhoneStatusBar(1284): disable: < EXPAND icons alerts TICKER system_info back* home* RECENT clock* SEARCH* >
10-28 16:14:03.589: V/KeyguardServiceDelegate(989): onScreenTurnedOn(showListener = com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager$25@45a6a158)
10-28 16:14:03.859: I/qdhwcomposer(320): handle_blank_event: dpy:0 panel power state: 1
10-28 16:14:03.869: D/qdhwcomposer(320): hwc_blank: Done unblanking display: 0
10-28 16:14:03.919: I/Choreographer(1614): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-28 16:14:03.929: E/XperiaLockscreen(1284): Setting cancellation runnable when already set
10-28 16:14:03.939: D/FULLockscreen(1284): Binding to Face Unlock service for user=0
```

And here is my `Activity`:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.HapticFeedbackConstants;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class AlarmAlert extends Activity {

    ScheduledFuture<?> autoSnooze;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    boolean isResumed = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("AlarmAlert", "onCreate CALLED");
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
                             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
                             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON|
                             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON|
                             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_alert);
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        autoSnooze = scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                snoozeAndFinish();
            }
        }, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        ((ResizeButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_snooze)).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(AlarmHome.isSmall(this) ? R.drawable.ic_clock_scalable : R.drawable.ic_clock, 0, 0, 0);
        ((ResizeButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_dismiss)).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(AlarmHome.isSmall(this) ? R.drawable.ic_stop_scalable : R.drawable.ic_stop, 0, 0, 0);
        Log.d("AlarmAlert", "onCreate DONE");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        Log.d("AlarmAlert", "onBackPressed");
        snoozeAndFinish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        isResumed = true;
        Log.d("AlarmAlert", "onResume");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        isResumed = false;
        Log.d("AlarmAlert", "onPause");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        if (this.isFinishing()) {
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Alarm.ALARM_ALERT_DISMISS));
        }
        Log.d("AlarmAlert", "onStop");
    }

    private void dismiss(){
        Log.d("AlarmAlert", "dismiss");
        autoSnooze.cancel(false);
        if (!prefs.getBoolean("alarmRepeat", false))
            Alarm.cancel(getApplicationContext());
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Alarm.ALARM_ALERT_DISMISS));
        if (isResumed)
            finish();
    }

    public void dismiss(View view){
        view.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.VIRTUAL_KEY);
        dismiss();
    }

    private void snooze(){
        Log.d("AlarmAlert", "snooze");
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Alarm.ALARM_ALERT_DISMISS));
        autoSnooze.cancel(false);
        Alarm.set(this, System.currentTimeMillis() + 5*60*1000);
    }

    private void snoozeAndFinish(){
        snooze();
        if (isResumed)
            finish();
    }

    public void snooze(View view){
        view.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.VIRTUAL_KEY);
        snoozeAndFinish();
    }
}
```

I am hopeless, does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: kill the unprocessed thread execution on calling the second function.

Comment: I've tried it and it wasn't the only thing that was causing this issue. I'll post answer.

Comment: Log the context of the Activity in onStop() and onPause() - perhaps it is not the same instance.

Comment: @ChrisStratton It was running in singleInstance mode.

Comment: That's useful to know, but if it were my puzzle, I'd still check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've killed the unprocessed thread execution in `onStop()`, after that first execution of the app was fine. But other time the activity was created, it kept crashing with the same error.

This activity is started by a receiver, where i call `Alarm.startRinging(Context)` and some other time, when user leaves the activity i call `Alarm.stopRinging()`. In the first method, I stored a reference of a `Ringtone` object in a static variable. In the second method I've executed `ringtone.stop()`.

I've created a service with non-static `Ringtone` variable for playing sounds and it now works.

Comment: that was a simple problem occurred at programming side and good to know that you have fixed it. unprocessed thread execution waste a serious amount of time of programmers as they are not able to find the reason. hope i helped you a bit. thanks :)